# The functions && Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I did my best with this program but I could not know where is the error?? I'll explain the program. In this program I should implement a stack of integers as linked list, using a global variable to **point** to the top of the stack by using these methods:

```
int push(int i);
```

push i on the stack, return 1 if successful else return 0.

```
int pop();
```

pop number from stack. if stack empty return 0;

I did create new method call `int stackEmpty();`  and the two method above.

Every time I run my program it's push the numbers into the stack but the pop doesn't work. Here my code:::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack Stack;
struct stack
{
    int number;
    Stack *next;
};
Stack *top = NULL;

int push(int i);
int count();
int stackEmpty();
int pop();

int main()
{
    char op;
    int i, x;
    printf("Welcome to my stack\n");
    printf("p to pop, s to push, c to count, q to quit\n");

    while (op != 'q')
    {
        scanf("%c", &op);
        if (op == 'p')
        {
            x = pop();
            if (x == 0)
            {
                printf("Stack is empty\n");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d popped\n", pop());
            }
        }
        else if (op == 'c')
        {
            i = count();
            printf("%d  numbers on stack\n", i);
        }
        else if (op == 's')
        {
            printf("Enter number: ");
            scanf("%d", &i);
            x = push(i);
            if (x == 1 || x == 2)
            {
                printf("%d puched :: state%d\n", i, x);
            }
            else
            {
                printf("faill %d\n", x);
            }
        }
        else if (op == 'q')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int stackEmpty()
{
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int count()
{
    int counter = 0;
    if (top == NULL)
    {
        return counter;
    }
    else
    {
        while (top != NULL)
        {
            top = top->next;
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }
}

int push(int i)
{
    Stack *head;
    Stack *next;
    Stack *new;
    int state;
    int m;
    head = top;

    new = (Stack *) malloc(sizeof(Stack));
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        state = 0;
    } new->number = i;
    m = stackEmpty();

    if (m == 1)
    {
        head = new;
        top = head;
        head->next = NULL;
        state = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while (head != NULL)
        {
            if ((next = head->next) == NULL)
                next = new;
            next->next = NULL;
            state = 2;
            break;
            head = top->next;
            next = head->next;
        }
        top = head;
    }
    return state;
}

int pop()
{
    Stack *head;
    int state;
    int m;
    head = top;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        state = 0;
    }
    m = stackEmpty();

    if (m == 1)
    {
        state = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        state = head->number;
        top = head->next;
        free(head);
    }
    return state;

}
```

Comment: Any chance you can format that a bit more pleasantly?

Comment: @KerrekSB: Is that more pleasant?

Comment: @KerrekSB: I just put it into Eclipse and autoformatted. But it revealed an error -- there's an `if` with no braces and several lines of code after it, including a `break;` inside the `while` loop of `push()`. I got suspicious when I saw the `break;` with unreachable code after it.

Answer (score 4):

Several problems:

1. `top` is your supposed head of the stack I assume. In `count` you advance top until it is `NULL` - thus once you called `count` you have "lost" your stack.
2. A stack is a LIFO queue (last in first out). Your push would implement a FIFO (first in first out) by appending new elements at the end.
3. Your push is not actually adding anything to the list. You are just assiging `new` to `next` but you are not pointing to next from anywhere in your list.
4. When using `pop` you are calling it twice (once for removing the element and once for printing). Therefore you remove two elements whenever you go down that code path. A better implementation would be to write a `peek` function which returns the top element without removing it and the `pop` function simply removes it (indicating success with 1 and fail with 0)

A push for a stack goes like this:

- Create a new element
- Point to your current head as the next element
- Make your new element the new head of the stack

No loop needed. It's an O(1) operation.

Answer (score 1):

You are not pushing correctly. You are changing *next* which is a local variable. you are not changing the "next" value in you list tail.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you `pop()`, then check result, then `pop()` again while printing.  You're popping twice for each time you try to print.

Answer (score 0):

Another error:

```
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if ((next = head->next) == NULL)
            next = new;
        next->next = NULL;
        state = 2;
        break;
        head = top->next;
        next = head->next;
    }
```

Should be:

```
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        if ((next = head->next) == NULL)
        {
            next = new;
            next->next = NULL;
            state = 2;
            break;
        }

        head = top->next;
        next = head->next;
    }
```

At least, that's what your original indentation seems to indicate.